# Class name conflicts in module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I am implementing a client web application that connects to an API using Omniauth, following instruction [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/353-oauth-with-doorkeeper?view=asciicast)

I have a class defined in a nested module in `/lib/omniauth/strategies/testservice.rb`

```
module OmniAuth:: Strategies
    class Testservice < OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2
      option :name, :testservice
    end
end
```

When I invoke the following in Rails console:

```
require File.expand_path('lib/omniauth/strategies/testservice', Rails.root)
```

it will fail.

However, if I shorten the name of the class `Testservice` to a single word, such as `Test`, then it works.

I suspect that my class name conflicts with Rails naming convention. I can't create the class name as TestService due to some constraints from Omniauth gem.

How can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `OmniAuth.config.add_camelization 'testservice', 'TestService` fixes the issue. [See more here](https://github.com/railsjedi/omniauth-angellist/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategies/angel_list.rb)

Answer (score 0):

In case of conflicts use fully qualified class name i.e along with the package name something like com.test.Test . It will help you to avoid the conflicts